# Making straight quotes in TeX appear as straight quotes in document

Tags: macros, symbols, quotation

So I'm writing a book, and I've used straight quotes (") in my latex files throughout the entire project. Now whenever I compile my document in Overleaf, these, to no ones surprise, come out as no starting quote, and a straight quote at the end of what's quoted.

What I wish is for all straight quotes in my tex files is to actually appear as straight quotes in the generated pdf, regardless of whether they are situated at the front or end of a word. Here's an example:

```latex
% In my .tex file
This is a "nice quote".
```

I want this to appear exactly like this in my document:
This is a "nice quote".

Is there anything I can do to override the default behaviour? I really do not want to go through my entire project consisting of many .tex files finding and replacing characters, all I want is simply the straight quote symbol to appear as an actual straight quote in my text regardless of whether it's a start-quote or an end-quote.

Comment: You can use regular expression to find and replace the quotes easily.

Comment: @Stephen So there is no simple macro to work around this? I'm on Overleaf and would thus have to download and reupload the entire project in order to do this.

Comment: See this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/imkMEz/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is [the one suggested by @Stephen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693088/making-straight-quotes-in-tex-appear-as-straight-quotes-in-document/693089#comment1719880_693088). But you can use `\textquotesdbl` if you want.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    This is how quotes are ``supposed to be''.

    But you can use straight ones \textquotedbl{}if you really\textquotedbl{} like them...
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace *exactly* `"` with `\textquotedbl{}`, you should have the result you are looking for (with no extra or missing spaces).

You can also redefine the meaning of `"` --- but this is dangerous and can become a problem with a lot of packages (`babel` and `tikz` just to name a couple of them):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Use at your own risk. It will probably break *everything*
\catcode`"=\active\def"{\textquotedbl}
\begin{document}
    This is how quotes are ``supposed to be''.

    But you can use straight ones "if you really" like them...
\end{document}
```